# Gitlab CI/CD pre-filled variables on manual job

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I'm looking for the right way to set up a variable when I launch a job manually.
I tried :

```
stages:
  - test 

my_job:
  stage: test 
  script:
    - echo "HEY"
  variables:
    FIRST_VARIABLE: "my_variable"
    SECOND_VARIABLE: 
      value: "a"
      description: "b"
  when: manual
```

I want my **SECOND_VARIABLE** to appear into the following **VARIABLES** field, with a pre-field value : **a**.
[image]

Unfortunatly, I got some error trying *"variables config should be a hash of key value pairs"* error.

I tried with the gitlab documentation (cf variables), but it fails.

Can you help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is currently not implemented, it is supported on the `New Pipeline` Form but not for manual steps - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/30101 is a good resource, where you can easily track the progress.

There are tickets in the backlog like https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/22629 - but as said currently this is not possible to be prefilled.

Comment: For those looking for what the OP is asking for. See this issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/301061 its set to be released FY22
Q4. I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible in GitLab 13.7+ and **works only with global variables**:

```
variables:
  DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT:
    value: "staging"  # Deploy to staging by default
    description: "The deployment target. Change this variable to 'canary' or 'production' if needed."
```

As a result you should see DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT variable with 'staging' prefilled and proper description.
Check the documention for more info: [Prefill variables in manual pipelines](https://git.ispconfig.org/help/ci/pipelines/index.md#prefill-variables-in-manual-pipelines)

Comment: This only works when using the "Run pipeline" option from the main pipelines page. It does not work when triggering a `when: manual` job from a pipeline that has already been created.

Comment: For some reason, if you omit the "description" entry, the lint will tell you everything is ok, but the variable won't show up in the UI. So my understanding is that value and description are mandatory if you want them to be prefilled in the "Run pipeline" page.